# Direct sums of subspaces (example question)

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

If $X=\{(x,0) ; x \in \Bbb R\}$ find infinitely many subspaces $Z_i$ such that $\Bbb R^2=X \oplus Z_i$.

I thought anwser would be $Y = \{(0,x) ; x \in \Bbb R\}$ so that $X\cap Y=\{0\}$. However the anwser is;

"Every line L,of non-zero gradient that passes through the origin is a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ such that $X \oplus L=\Bbb R^2$"

Comment: what is $I\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: well, you only gave one example of a subspace so clearly you didnt do what was asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is fine, but the question was to find infinitely many examples. In fact, from the requirement $\Bbb R^2=X \oplus Z_i$ you know that $Z_i$ has to have dimension $1$ and intersect $X$ trivially. Therefore any line fits these requirements, excepts for $X$ itself.

Comment: I am not very confident about my knowledge on direct sums sorry if I am stating something obvious. Any other line other then Y I have written in the question, under addition with X would be equal to R^2 however would not be direct as there won't be an unique way to represent every vector

Comment: Yes there will. For instance try to find $a$ and $b$ such that $(2,3)=a(1,0)+b(1,1)$. You will find that there is exactly one solution. You can replace $(1,1)$ in this example by any particular $(x,y)$ such that $y\neq 0$ (that is, the determinant of $\left(\matrix{1&0\\x&y}\right)$ is not $0$).